# Is there a term for 'complementary factor'?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, factoring

Please forgive this incredibly lame question, but if I have factor $n$ of $x,$ and I find its *complementary factor* $y= \frac xn$, does that complementary factor $y$ have a specific name?

I haven't been able to find one.

EDIT: As I mention in a comment below, I'm not trying to understand the concept; I'm looking for a piece of jargon that will make it easier to write a terse but descriptive function identifier.

**EDIT 2: As @timtfj indicates in their comment directly beneath this question, I'm talking about a symmetrical term, *not* a unidirectional term such as "quotient". It seems (again based on comments) that "complementary factor" is acceptable, but I'm leery of writing my own answer to this question.**

Comment: I don’t think we have a name for this, but the terminology you suggest is fine

Comment: @Randall Ah, okay. Thank you!

Comment: *Complementary factor* seems clear and accurate—in particular it's nicely symmetrical (if $xy=n$ then $x$ and $y$ form a complementary pair of factors of $n$, and both have the same status).

Comment: @timtfj Oh oh, okay this is very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should feel free to post your own answer. As with the other commenters, I think your terminology is fine. The only advice I have regarding your naming convention is to perhaps avoid cofactor as it might make one think of matrices (though [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor) does have an entry with precisely your desired definition).

Comment: @Clayton Much obliged for this! I actually considered cofactor for the reason you mention, but it's interesting that Wikipedia defines it as such. In fact it seems that "co-", as a prefix, is simply shorthand for "complement" in this sense. But I think I shall follow your advice and stick with the expanded "complementary factor" for the sake of resolving a potential ambiguity. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line with some of the comments I've received, I'm going to stick with "complementary factor".

As @Clayton points out in one such comment, "cofactor" has an [entry on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor) congruent with my requirement. In fact, it seems "co-" as a prefix is a [common shortening](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/co-) of "complementary" in this regard.

However – again, as @Clayton points out – "cofactor" tends to evoke matrices, so to avoid any potential ambiguity I will use the full form.

Many thanks to everybody who weighed in!